# C: working with void pointer arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, void-pointers

I'm a novice with C and am still weak when it comes to using and understanding pointers - especially void pointers.  I'm attempting to write a function that loads data from a file and stores those data in a void pointer array, such that each element of the array has (in this example) the string from that line of the file.  I suspect that there are several problems with the code:

1. I'm not sure if I'm properly using *voidArray[] as one of the function's arguments.
2. I'm not sure if strcpy() is a good approach for copying the line buffer's contents into the pertinent array element.
3. I don't know what the proper syntax is for strcpy()'s destination (i.e. the pertinent element in the void pointer array).

There could be other errors as well, but those are the three issues I feel very unsure about.

Here's my function:

```c
void *readData(void *voidArray[], const char *filename, int lines) {
    FILE *stream = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (stream == NULL) {
        perror("Error loading file");
    return 1;
    }
    char lineBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

int i = 0;
    while(!feof(stream)) {
        while(fgets(lineBuffer, sizeof(lineBuffer), stream)) {
            // *voidArray[i] = malloc(strlen(lineBuffer) + 1);     // probably not what I want
            strcpy(*voidArray[i], lineBuffer);
            i++;
        }
    }

    fclose(stream);
}
```

...and here's the beginning of main(), where (again) I'm not sure what the proper syntax is for declaring (and initializing?) the array:

```c
int main(void)
{
    int lines = 20;
    void *varray[lines];
    // varray = malloc(sizeof(char *) * lines);     // probably not what I want
    readData(varray[lines], FILENAME, lines);       // FILENAME declared earlier
```

Some suggested code fixes would be sorely appreciated (especially if I'm completely missing the boat on a more appropriate approach), but what I feel like I need even more is a good explanation for **why** the suggestions are correct.  If I can wrap my head around this problem I think - at worst - I'll have a good sense of what I still need to teach myself re: pointers.  Thank you in advance for any help or commentary, and for your patience in reading this far.

---

Edit:  Joachim Pileborg's answer has helped, but I'm still missing something fundamental (and probably obvious).  Here is my revised function:

```
void *loadData(void *voidArray, const char *filename, int lines) {
    FILE *stream = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (stream == NULL) {
        perror("Error loading file");
    }
    char lineBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    int i = 0;
    while(fgets(lineBuffer, sizeof(lineBuffer), stream)) {
        strcpy((voidArray+i), lineBuffer);
        printf("voidArray: %s\n", (char *)(voidArray+i));
        i++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        printf("array element %d: %s\n", i, (char *)(voidArray+i));
    }

    fclose(stream);
}
```

And here are the results from my two tests:

```
voidArray: Good
voidArray: morning
voidArray: everyone
array element 0: Gmeveryone
array element 1: meveryone
array element 2: everyone
```

Again, I'm probably missing something trivial.  What I want to do is have varray comprised of void pointers, each of which points to an object (for this example, a string) read from an external file.  I have a sense of what I'm doing wrong with "varray+i", but I don't know what I should actually be doing instead.

Comment: You don't need the outer loop (the `while (!feof(...))` loop). In fact, it might cause an infinite loop, if there is an error reading the file before you hit the end of the file.

Comment: If you store chars, why not just use char arrays, char pointers? You Don'tneed void for that

Comment: Ah, I think you're right about the outer loop's redundancy.  Thank you!  There was no error reading any of the files I created for testing, and reading file lines into the buffer is one of the few aspects of this function I'm sure is working as intended.

Comment: Buella Gabor - I want the ability to store ints or doubles as well, depending on the file (and obviously I'd need to tweak the data-reading function accordingly).  To shorten the amount of code I presented I used just the case of chars.

Comment: In the original, you wanted `voidArray[i] = malloc( strlen(X) + 1 ); strcpy( voidArray[i], X);`. And you call it with `readData(varray, FILENAME, lines);`. That was fine. The revised version doesn't make sense. as you only pass in a single buffer yet you seem to want to store multiple strings in it. What you are seeing is the results of copying strings over the top of each other, starting one place later in the same buffer each time, which is what your revised version does.

Comment: Matt McNabb - Aha!  I see now, and was able to modify the code and resolve my original problem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four problems (besides the one I mentioned in the comment) that I see at a quick glance:

- The first is that you commented out the allocation, so if the the pointers aren't allocated when you call the function you will write to what will seem random locations in memory.
- The second is that you use the dereference operator in your call to `strcpy`. If you had for example an array of `char` pointers, this would be a single `char` and not a pointer. And that's besides the fact that you can't actually dereference a `void` pointer.
- The third problem is that you never check the number of entries in the array, you just keep on looping and reading and copying into the array without regards for its size.
- The fourth problem is in the way you call this function, where you actually aren't passing an array of pointers, but a single pointer at the index `lines`, which will be one beyond the limits of the array.

---

As an unrelated side-note: Remember that if [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) reads a newline, then that newline will be in the buffer.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I have two questions, if it's alright:

1. I'm not sure I understand the third problem.  In main I specify a specific number of elements for the array (i.e. the number of lines in the file).

2. How would I go about fixing problem 4?

Comment: @jda You pass in the number of elements in the array to the function (the `lines` argument), you have to make you never read more than this (and remember that array indexes range from zero to size-minus-one). For the second question, simply don't use array indexing.

Comment: Thank you again.  I have updated my question and hopefully narrowed its scope a bit.  My problem is that I don't know what sort of syntax I should be using to access the various void pointers in the array without utilizing array indexing.  I made an attempt, but the printed tests show that I'm indexing incorrectly.  I think if I can just understand this part, I should be at the point where I can explore and investigate without feeling hamstrung.

Answer (score -2):

You can't store stuff in void pointers, nor can you index into them. You cannot dereference void pointers unless you cast them first. You can't do pointer arithmetic with them. They are syntactic sugar for generics which was added later because people were using char* for that purpose.

Comment: `void *x; *x = 5;` is illegal is what I meant. In comparison, `int *x; *x = 5;` is legal

Comment: Thank you, v3ga!  I'm actually hoping to tie this into a quicksort.  If I scrap the function and just write everything in main() while using (for example) char pointers, I can make things work without issue.  So the next step for me (I hope) seems to be understanding void pointers and their proper syntax and logic.

Comment: @jda: `void*`are easy, there are only two rules: Any data pointer can be converted to/back from `void*` without cast or loss of information. Casting, copying and equality comparison are the only useful operations on `void*`.

Comment: @v3ga your answer it way too sparse and doesn't explain much, especially to a novice.

Comment: `int *x; *x = 5;` is NOT legal

Comment: oops. you're right. `*x=5` is legal only if x is pointing to valid memory.